# Batch File to Delete any Users Not Mentioned in a Text File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have one text file with the names of a bunch authorized users in it *(README.txt)* and another text file with the names of all users on my computer in it *(USERS.txt)*. I want to create a batch file that disables any users not mentioned in *README.txt*.

Something worth mentioning is that *README.txt* is not in a list format, and that the names of the users are spread out throughout paragraphs of text.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of both files and provide an example of code you have already tried. Just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what both files look like this is my best guess.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (users.txt) DO (
    findstr /M /I /R /C:"\<%%G\>" README.TXT >nul ||net user %%G /active:no
)
```